# MonoGame iPhone iPad Setup

Tags: monogame

I recently migrated a WP7 XNA app to MonoGame. When I build, I get an error saying there is no graphics device manager. Here is the code:

MonoGame.Framework.MacOS > Game.cs

```
    private GraphicsDeviceManager graphicsDeviceManager
    {
        get
        {
            if (_graphicsDeviceManager == null)
            {
                _graphicsDeviceManager = (IGraphicsDeviceManager)
                    Services.GetService(typeof(IGraphicsDeviceManager));

                if (_graphicsDeviceManager == null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException ("No Graphics Device Manager");
            }
            return (GraphicsDeviceManager)_graphicsDeviceManager;
        }
    }
```

It appears that my game class never starts. I created a MacOS project for the game. Did I use the incorrect one? I am following these steps to make an iPad / iPhone game: http://www.facepuncher.com/blogs/10parameters/?p=42

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create a MacOS project it will try and target MacOS. If you have MonoTouch installed you should be able to create an iOS project which will allow you to target iPhone/iPod/iPad.

The instructions from the site you posted are for a MacOS project.

We hope to include MonoGame project templates in the near future.

I hope this helps.